# I get "enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory" whenever I try to create a React project with "npx create-react-app"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I tried creating a new React project:

```
(node:4840) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Afrifa\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Afrifa\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Afrifa\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-16T23_49_01_429Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have node.js and npm installed. If they are installed try to delete and reinstall `node_modules`.
You can also try to uninstall "create-react-app" using the `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` command and install with `npm install -g create-react-app` command.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Uninstalling and reinstalling create-react-app did not help me. Then I executed
**`npm install -g npm`**
And it fixed the issue.